# Power In= Power Out in transformers

Tags: power, transformer, power-electronics

In transformers, we prove that the induced voltage per turn is the same in both primary and the secondary coils of the transformers, i:e (Ep/Np)=(Es/Ns). But when it comes to currents, we show that (Ip/Np= **-** Is/Ns), which should yeld to (Ep x Ip= **-** Es x Is). This equation should yeld to say that Power in is opposite to power out, or Pin=-Pout.
Beside this we say that Power supplied to the primary coil is equal to the power supplied to the second coil.
What did I miss from this concept of power transfer in transformers ? how do I should understand or explain the existence of the minus sign in the currents and the equality of the **power In** and **Out**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *But when it comes to currents, we show that \$\dfrac{Ip}{Np} = -\dfrac{Is}{Ns}\$*

Yes, that relationship is true: -

[image]

But it doesn't mean that the power out to the load is negative (see the above picture). It just means that as far as the transformer is concerned, the current is flowing outward with respect to the primary winding.

The 1 ohm load still receives positive power as if it were fed from a voltage source. The secondary produces a current opposite to the primary (in that the current is flowing away from the transformer) but, it is still flowing in the correct direction for positive power into the resistor load.

> *Beside this we say that Power supplied to the primary coil is equal to
>   the power supplied to the second coil.*

An ideal transformer doesn't deal with watts; it deals with volts and amps so we talk about \$VA\$ and that makes it clearer in my book. Power is supplied to the load; it isn't supplied to the secondary and it isn't really supplied to the primary. Both primary and secondary deal in volts and amps. That's why we talk about transformers having a \$VA\$ rating.

Comment: So the direction or the sign of the secondary current is relative. i:e is negative compared to the input current, but it is still positive to the load.

Comment: Correct, current is relative to the transformer but still the right direction for positive power to the load.

Comment: @luxinapado which book do you refer to? Oh "clearer in my book" - it's an English phrase that means "clearer to me" or "clearer in my opinion"!!!

Comment: ahhhh idioms... another thing to note, Andy, is that this depends on the construction of the transformer. This is why you will sometimes see dots on transformer markings. If the windings are done in the same direction, you get positive voltage (as you show above), but it can be done the other way as well.

Comment: @Stiddily - it makes no difference - if the windings are reversed then you get negative voltage and positive current into the transformer - note that the power is still positive as far as the load is concerned so I'm unsure what your point is. Can you explain? Maybe I've missed something?

Comment: I was trying to explain how you can shift the phase of an AC signal (or not) depending on which way you wind the coil. https://images.app.goo.gl/h5iLScExRau2AWX68 something like this image here.

Comment: Yes, but who were you trying to explain that to and is it really relevant here? If you think it is then why not add an answer? Just because i don't see the relevance doesn't mean that I'm not being stupid.